# Differencen between two times in R

Tags: r

I am using the start.time at the start of the program and end.time at the end of the program.However i am getting the below error

```
> time.taken <- end.time - start.time
Error: object 'start.time' not found
> time.taken
Error: object 'time.taken' not found
```

I have used the below code but i am getting the above error

```
start.time <- Sys.time()
...Relevent codes...
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce; `start.time <- Sys.time()`; `x = 1`; `end.time <- Sys.time()`; `end.time - start.time`; `Time difference of 0.001006126 secs`. Have you tried turning it off and on again...

Comment: No issues with the code presented, perhaps one of your star/end times were taken in a different environment then the one you are trying to calculate in?

Comment: could you please help me with an example as i am not able to understand about "different Environment"?